# need delay function in c#

Tags: c#

I have a *problem using* **Thread.sleep(seconds)**, it pauses all my execution in sleeping state.  But I tried another solutions **also using for loop**, however what I'm expecting it's not working.

When the login button is clicked:

1. Action report="on progressing";
2. After another 2 seconds it will be "trying to connect to the database"
3. then after opening database it will be like "database connected successfully"

Here is the code:

```
private void Loginbtn_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   if(userText.Text!=String.Empty && passText.Password!=String.Empty){
   ProgressForm.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
   LoginForm.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
   delay(2);
   actionReport.Text = "Try to Connecting the database";
   String ConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;pwd='';database=smsdb;";
   MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);

   try {
      con.Open();
      delay(2);
      actionReport.Text = "Database Connected Sucessfully";
       } 

   catch(MySqlException sqle){
      actionReport.Text = sqle.Message; 
  }
} 
    else {
   MessageBox.Show("Please enter the user name and password to verify","Notification",MessageBoxButton.OK,MessageBoxImage.Information);
     }
 }

private void delay(int seconds) 
{
for(long i=0;i<seconds*3600; i++){
//empty
}
```

Please someone help me.

Comment: What is your problem? It sounds you're abusing the UI thread.

Comment: My first question to you, is why do you want a delay there?

Comment: 7200 iterations of doing *nothing* in a loop is not going to take a long time. Certainly not 2 seconds. But you *don't* want to do busy work, you *don't* want to put threads to sleep. But I guess a more pressing question is, why do you want to introduce arbitrary delays?

Comment: If you don't like sleep, the second and third answers to this question may provide you with some other alternative suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234793/how-to-make-a-function-timedelay-by-5-seconds

Answer (score 3):

`await` (introduced in C# 5.0) with `Task.Delay` makes this trivially easy:

```
public async void Loginbtn_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    actionReport.Text = "Trying to Connecting to the database";
    await Task.Delay(2);
    actionReport.Text = "Connected";
}
```

For a C# 4.0 solution it's a tad messier, but not a whole lot:

```
public async void Loginbtn_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    actionReport.Text = "Trying to Connecting to the database";
    Task.Delay(2).ContinueWith(_ =>
        {
            actionReport.Text = "Connected";
        }, CancellationToken.None
        , TaskContinuationOptions.None
        , TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

The key point here is that at no point are you blocking the UI thread, you're simply letting the UI thread continue on processing events for two seconds before giving it something to do.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer like this

```
delay("Try to Connecting the database");
```

delay like this.

```
public void delay(string message) {
    var frame = new DispatcherFrame();
    new Thread((ThreadStart)(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
        frame.Continue = false;
    })).Start();
Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
        actionReport.Text=message;
    }
```

Thanks friends!
to reply me.

Answer (score -1):

You first need to look up and understand performing processing on a background thread. The main rules being;

1. You should never block the UI
2. don't try to talk to the UI thread from a background thread
3. If you call Thread.Sleep, it's probably wrong

Your questions demonstrate an opportunity for you to learn new architectural patterns. These look like good candidates;

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99143/BackgroundWorker-Class-Sample-for-Beginners

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26148/Beginners-Guide-to-Threading-in-NET-Part-1-of-n

Comment: Downvote wasn't mine (don't have the rep). But I would like to hear your reasoning for #2. In a lot of my project I let the user launch large tasks which kick off as a background worker, and as steps of these tasks finish they report back to the UI (sometimes just in the form of a log, other times updating images/labels). This allows the user to continue using the program for other uses while they lengthy work completes.

Comment: sorry, should have been more explicit. You should not communicate directly from the background thread to the thread on which a control was created. There are several mechanisms for to facilitate this and the best one for you depends on many things from which version of the framework to winForms vs WPF and other aproaches with your applicatio architecture. I would highly recommend reading around the subject to best understand the problem

Comment: I found answer, like this var frame = new DispatcherFrame();
    new Thread((ThreadStart)(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds));
            frame.Continue = false;
        })).Start();
    Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);